# Я тут задание выполнял и не понимаю в чём дело.... c++

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, указатели

задание: 4. Создать структуру, которая хранит имя человека и его номер телефона. Создать очередь из 5-ти структур и вывести результат. Помним, что в очереди кто первым записался, тот первым и обслуживается.
У меня выскакивает ошибка [image: вот такая]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct str
{
    string name;
    int number;
    str* next;
};

int main()
{
    str* first = new str;
    str* tekp = new str;
    str* tek = new str;
    delete tek;
    cout << "Enter name 1 man: ";
    cin >> first->name;
    cout << "Enter number 1 man: ";
    cin >> first->number;
    for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2) {
            str* tek = new str;
            first->next = tek;
            tekp = tek;

        }
        else
        {
            str* tek = new str;
            tek->next = tekp;
            tekp = tek;
        }
        cout << "Enter name " << i << " man: ";
        cin >> tek->name;
        cout << "Enter number " << i << " man: ";
        cin >> tek->number;
        

    }
    str * uq = first;
    while (uq)
    {
        cout << uq->name << " " << uq->number << "\n";
        uq = uq->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я полагаю, что у вас возникло исключение: нарушение прав доступа для чтения. Не нарушайте права доступа для чтения, и исключение не будет возникать. `//быть может у вас какой-то указатель имеет значение nullptr?`

Comment: Подсказка: `if (i == 0) {...}` - что с этим не так?

Comment: @LShadouw77 я исправил проблему с if и не один указатель не равен nullptr

Comment: А зачем у вас такой интересный код? `str* tek = new str; delete tek;`?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 1):

Намекаю большим намеком:

```
str* tek = new str;
delete tek;
```

Теперь `tek` указывает... да в никуда. На освобожденную память.

```
    if (i == 2) {
        str* tek = new str;
```

Тут вы работаете с вот этим `tek`, из предыдущей строки.

```
        first->next = tek;
        tekp = tek;
    }
    else
    {
        str* tek = new str;
```

И тут тоже вы работаете с вот этим `tek`, из предыдущей строки.

```
        tek->next = tekp;
        tekp = tek;
    }
```

А с **КАКИМ** `tek` вы имеете дело в следующих строках?

```
    cout << "Enter name " << i << " man: ";
    cin >> tek->name;
    cout << "Enter number " << i << " man: ";
    cin >> tek->number;
```

Надеюсь, это вас научит внимательнее смотреть на предупреждения компилятора, а заодно именовать свои переменные разнообразнее...

Comment: Кстати стало интересно, есть ли отличие между `delete[]` и просто `delete` ?Во втором так же очищает память?

Comment: @Miracle- Очищает. Но, например, деструкторы не вызывает... Вобщем, если не хотите UB, то для массивов используйте `delete[]`.